# Export HTML from InDesign or FrameMaker with tree index like Help and Manual

Tags: export, adobe-indesign, framemaker

I am looking into the ability of generating HTML exports from Adobe Indesign or Adobe FrameMaker that give me index navigation in a panel on the left and the content in the main panel. So I can easily navigate around the book by clicking the links in the index navigation.

The aim of which is to publish a book online that is currently published in hardcopy where the content is created in Indesign. I can do something like this in [Help and Manual][1] very easily.

I am new to these products and not sure if this is supported without a high level of complexity. Any advice appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

This is easier to do from FrameMaker than from InDesign. Via FrameMaker, you have a number of options:

- Use the Tech Comm Suite (of which FM is a component) to link your FrameMaker files into RoboHelp, then publish through RoboHelp to WebHelp output.
- Get a copy of a third-party converter, such as MIF2GO or ePublisher Pro, and use them to convert from FM to WebHelp output.

In theory, you can convert your FrameMaker content to HTML, then process that HTML to create WebHelp. In practice, this approach is unusable because the HTML output is rudimentary.

From InDesign, you can export to EPUB, but if you want WebHelp, you'll probably need to go to HTML and then repurpose the HTML via a help authoring tool.